# mamp install and joomla

Tags: joomla, mamp

[image: dragging joomla onto Mamp]

Using Yosemite on Mac installing Mamp and Mamp pro and trying to see the way it works as a unit. Can I just drag it into the folder as shown or must I upload it via the application? The download did not dialogue where the install sh/b put for the first option. Suggest that sh/b clarified at outset.

Answer (score 1):

Take this steps:

1 - Install the Mamp (copy to application folder)

2 - Open the application folder, right click on Mamp and click on "show package contents". I think the below path is your root folder of web (www)

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/
```

3 - copy your joomla files in this folder and rename it to something easier ("joomla" for example)

4 - open the Mamp application and start your web server (apache I think)

5 - Access the installer by the name of folder in "htdocs". for example:

```
http://localhost/joomla
```

Comment: Thanks for answering with what makes sense if it worked in a perfect world. Mine is not. I don't have a right click button. A Mac doesn't have a hierarchical window structure. If I go to find and folder Mamp I'd have to minimize one and drag and drop. Then the whole joomla folder disappeared or just sits in beside Mamp. If my description wasn't clear I can do a series of pics step by step linked by hyperlink. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Right then, will do. Sound like instructions to an idiot (me) but I hate to mess with databases inside a prepackaged environment not knowing their after-effects. thx